# HTML combo Dropdown: JavaScript redirect based on geographic location

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml, location

I'm looking for some help with an issue I am having.

Developing a site which needs to recognize a users geographic location, then automatically select the relevant item from a dropdown list - this then triggers a link to the relevant site for their region.

3 sites - UK, EU, USA.

I have the dropdown box working with links, however I can't get the automatic change to trigger. Currently trying a JS geoplugin (which has worked on a previous site) however I can't get it to work on this site.

Any help with this matter would be greatly appreciated

(I had to take the links out as don't have the reputation to post more than 2 links)

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dropdown-currency.css">
</head>


<script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
myCurrency.currecyList = '<select id="currencySelection">'
+ '<option countryType="UK" value="GBP">GBP</option>'
+ '<option countryType="EU" value="EUR">EUR</option>'
+ '<option countryType="USA" value="USD">USD</option>'
+ '</select>';
myCurrency.is = 'GBP'; //DEFAULT.
myCurrency.target = "#currencySelection";
myCurrency.twiceMode = false; 
myCurrency.exec();
</script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.getJSON("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?jsoncallback=?",
        function (data) {
            var continent = data["geoplugin_continentCode"];
            var country = data["geoplugin_countryCode"];
            if ( continent == 'EU' ) {
                if ( country != 'GB' ) {
                    // Europe - Euros
                    $("#currencySelection").val("EUR");
                    $("#currencySelection").change();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // USA, Canada & Rest of World - USD
                $("#currencySelection").val("USD");
                $("#currencySelection").change();
            }
        });

   });
   </script>



</script>

<body>
<br>
<br>

 <div class="currecyList">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="currencySelection" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="http://www.google.co.uk">GBP</a>
    <a href="http://www.google.ca">USD</a>
    <a href="#">EUR</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>



</html>
```

dropdown-currency.css

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.currecyList {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: show;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}

#currencySelection select{
    color: #888;
    border:1px solid #ebebeb;
```

Comment: Your script tags are wrapped by script tags - remove those. Also, have them either in the `<head>` or `<body>` element, not between the two.